# How to assign the src attribute of the nth child of an element to another element through JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm relatively new at this, but I found a program for a modal/dialog pop-up that uses images.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #myImg {
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

    .modal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-top: 100px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgba (0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    .modal-content {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width 80%;
        max-width: 80%;
    }
    #caption {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 700px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #CCC;
        padding: 10px 0;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .modal-content, #caption {
        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
        from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
        to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
    }
    .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
        color: #f1f1f1;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .close:hover, .close:focus {
        color: #BBB;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded' id="myImg" alt="Floor 1" width="300" height="200">
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01" >
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    img.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

This is the code for it and it works perfectly. My concern is with particular snippet:

```
    img.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
```

I am trying to use this onclick function on images nested within span tags. Is there a way to use an :nth-child selector within the function pasted above? Ideally the program will execute when the span is clicked, and the nested images' 'src' will be assigned here:

```
     <img class="modal-content" id="img01" >
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear what you mean by :nth-child selector but the usual process is that you first get the element source you want to copy like this:

`var source = document.getElementById('image').src`

then you assign that `src` to a different element like so:

`document.getElementById('image2').src = source;`

now as for how to select the second element (the element which you want to assign new `src` to it) it depends on where exactly it is located. can you please clarify?